# ASP.Net assign event handler to asp button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to assign event handler to the asp button click

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <div>
       <asp:Table id="tb" runat="server" Height="239px" Width="417px" >

       </asp:Table>

           </div>
    <table>
          <tr>
              <td></td><td><asp:Button ID="Votes" runat="server" Text="Vote" OnClick="Votes_Click" /></td>
          </tr>
      </table>

</asp:Content>
```

But when debugging the project and click the above button it execute page_load event not Votes_Click event

why it does that???
and how to solve this problem???

and the handle on code behind page is

```
protected void Votes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "btn",

     "<script type = 'text/javascript'>alert('Button Clicked');</script>");
            int i = 0;
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

        }
```

Comment: Page always executes Page_Load handler - it's a part of the page lifecycle. It executes control events after that. Can you put breakpoint in the `Votes_Click` handler and see if it gets there *after* page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.  If you want to avoid executing the code in the Page_Load event in the event of a postback, you can use the [`Page.IsPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property in a conditional statement.

Answer (score 3):

When your page posts back, it will always do a Page_Load().  It should then continue on to your event handlers.  If you continue debugging, does it get to your click event handler?

See [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your answer but I have created dynamic controls in page_load event. if it runs again, it will produce an error of Multiple controls with the same ID. what I have to do??